# get any non-error element from a list of deferred in OCaml/Async

Tags: asynchronous, error-handling, ocaml

Suppose I have a function such as:

```
query_server : Server.t -> string Or_error.t Deferred.t
```

Then I produce a list of deferred queries:

```
let queries : string Or_error.t Deferred.t list = List.map servers ~f:query_server
```

How to get the result of the first query that doesn't fail (or some error otherwise). Basically, I'd like a function such as:

```
any_non_error :  'a Or_error.t Deferred.t list -> 'a Or_error.t
```

Also, I'm not sure how to somehow aggregate the errors. Maybe my function needs an extra parameter such as `Error.t -> Error.t -> Error.t` or is there a standard way to combine errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use `Deferred.List` that contains list operations lifted into the Async monad, basically a container interface in the Kleisli category. We will try each server in order until the first one is ready, e.g.,

```
let first_non_error = 
  Deferred.List.find ~f:(fun s -> query_server s >>| Result.is_ok)
```

Of course, it is not `any_non_error`, as the processing is sequential. Also, we are losing the error information (though the latter is very easy to fix).

So to make it parallel, we will employ the following strategy. We will have two deferred computations, the first will run all queries in parallel and wait until all are ready, the second will become determined as soon as an Ok result is received. If the first one happens before the last one, then it means that all servers failed. So let's try:

```
 let query_servers servers = 
   let a_success,got_success = Pipe.create () in
   let all_errors = Deferred.List.map ~how:`Parallel servers ~f:(fun s -> 
      query_server s >>| function
      | Error err as e -> e
      | Ok x as ok -> Pipe.write_without_pushback x; ok) in
   Deferred.any [
       Deferred.any all_errors;
       Pipe.read a_success >>= function
       | `Ok x -> Ok x
       | `Eof -> assert false
   ]
```